# how to render javascript files at the end of body in reactjs+webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I created a reactjs+ webpack SPA and tested it on 'Google pagespeed insights'. I have just one main.js file and it's getting rendered at the beginning.
[here is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JULjo.png)

how do i resolve this ?

this is my webpack configuration :

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin({
      cache: true,
      parallel: true,
      // uglifyOptions: {
      //   compress: false,
      //   ecma: 6,
      //   mangle: true
      // },
    })]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader?cacheDirectory=true"
        }
      },
      {
        test:/\.css$/,
        use:['style-loader','css-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|woff|woff2)$/,
        use: {
          loader: "file-loader",
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|svg)$/,  
        use: [{
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: { 
                limit: 8000, // Convert images < 8kb to base64 strings
                name: 'static/[name].[ext]'
            } 
        }]
    },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html"
    })
  ]
};
```

how could i tell webpack to load the js file at the end of the body ? or any other solution that helps to solve this issue?

and my index.html and index.js files are so simple.

index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fa">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta
        name="viewport"
        content="minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="static/favicon.png"/>
    <title>آسان یادبگیر</title>
</head>
<body dir="rtl">
    <div id="mainDiv">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js :

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Theme from './styles/theme';
import { MuiThemeProvider} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import './styles/style.css';
import RTL from './jss-rtl';
import './static/favicon.png'
import App from './app';

ReactDOM.render(
    <RTL>
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={Theme}>
        <React.Fragment>
            <CssBaseline/>
            <App/>
        </React.Fragment>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    </RTL>,
    document.getElementById('mainDiv'));
```

here the google issue :

```
Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content: None of the above-the-fold content on your page could be rendered without waiting for the following resources to load. Try to defer or asynchronously load blocking resources, or inline the critical portions of those resources directly in the HTML.
```

Remove render-blocking JavaScript:
https://asanyadbegir.com/main.js

Comment: You need to share the minimum and relevant code for us to help you with the resolution

Comment: @Think-Twice I posted my webpack config file.

Comment: do you want to show all the .js files in webpage? is that your issue?

Comment: I want to get a higher score from 'google pagespeed insight'. I added google Suggestion to the end of my question.

Comment: I added  ' defer="true" '  to the dist/index.html file and it got better. but i don't think this is the real solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added ' defer="true" ' to the dist/index.html file and it got better(50% better). then by using React-Loadable I splited my files. every thing is file now.